Codeigniter in docker, dompdf not loading assets like css and images
i'm using codeigniter 4 and not having trouble with dompdf on a remote host, obviously setting like this:
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled',true);

The problem comes in docker multicontainers app, as when i try o open a pdf the data and html are loaded but css and images are not.. though if in my .env file i change the baseUrl from http://localhost to http://myapp_apache the css and images are loaded, clearly all the rest is not working anymore but it was just a test to better understand the problem..
It looks like the php container and the apache container are not comunicating correctly..
Below the docker-compose.yml i'm using
version: "3.7"

services:
  httpd:
    image: myapp/apache
    container_name: myapp_apache
    build:
      context: ./apache
    ports:
      - ${HTTP_PORT:-80}:80
    environment:
      - APACHE_LOG_DIR=/usr/local/apache2/logs
    volumes:
      - ../site:/var/www/html
      - ./apache/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
      - ./apache/my-project.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/my-project.conf
      - ./apache/php-fpm-proxy.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/php-fpm-proxy.conf
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm

  php-fpm:
    image: myapp/php
    container_name: myapp_php
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ../site:/var/www/html
      - ./php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:${MARIADB_TAG:-10.4}
    container_name: myapp_sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-NotSoSecret_password}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE:-myapp}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER:-user_admin}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-a123456}
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT:-3306}:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

  phpmyadmin: 
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-NotSoSecret_password}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-a123456}
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER:-user_admin}

  mailhog:
      image: mailhog/mailhog
      container_name: 'mailhog'
      ports:
        - "1025:1025"
        - "8025:8025"
      logging:
        driver: "none"


Your php container is not exposed, should it be? If yes, you could use a reverse proxy for routing, since exposing on different ports will give your CORS issues. (Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with codeigniter, if ever it performs forwarding)
